# Why won't my code stop running?

Tags: ruby, infinite-loop

I'm trying to solve [Problem #5](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=5) in Project Euler. The code works for the example, when I check the numbers from 1 to 10 I get 2520 as a result, which is right. But when I check for the numbers from 1 to 20, the code doesn't stop running.

Here it is:

```
num = 0

while true

    num += 1
    check = true

    for i in 1..20

        break unless check

        check = num%i==0

    end

    break if check

end

File.open("__RESULT__.txt", "w+").write num
```

Comment: Marc already gave a perfect answer. Alternatively: As every number has to be divisible by 20, `num += 20` will give you a 20x speedup. Also, use `for i in 2..20` as every number is divisible by 1

Comment: As a style note: Your code could be more idiomatically written as `inf = 1.0/0.0; num = (1..inf).find {|n| (1.20).all? {|i| x%i == 0}}` - but that wouldn't change the fact that it takes too long to compute.

Comment: Just checked my proposed slightly optimized version in Ruby. It takes about 1 minute here which is hard to the Project Euler limit and much slower than my C++ version that does the same in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution for that problem can not be found by just calculating every possible solution. The solution is so big, that it will take days (maybe years) to calculate.

There is a smarter solution using prime numbers to write down the numbers.

The example that is given (2520 is the smallest number that is divisable by the numbers 1 through 10) can be written down like this:

```
1 = 1 (can be skipped)  = 2^0 * 3^0 * 5^0 * 7^0
2 = 2 (prime)           = 2^1 * 3^0 * 5^0 * 7^0
3 = 3 (prime)           = 2^0 * 3^1 * 5^0 * 7^0
4 = 2^2                 = 2^2 * 3^0 * 5^0 * 7^0
5 = 5 (prime)           = 2^0 * 3^0 * 5^1 * 7^0
6 = 2 * 3               = 2^1 * 3^1 * 5^0 * 7^0
7 = 7 (prime)           = 2^0 * 3^0 * 5^0 * 7^1
8 = 2^3                 = 2^3 * 3^0 * 5^0 * 7^0
9 = 3^2                 = 2^0 * 3^2 * 5^0 * 7^0
10= 2 * 5               = 2^1 * 3^0 * 5^1 * 7^0
```

Now the smallest number that can be divided by these, can be calculated by using the maximum power that is used on each prime:

```
2^3 * 3^2 * 5^1 * 7^1 = 2520
```

The same can be performed (even by hand) on the numbers 1 through 20

*Last hint:* the answer is larger than 100.000.000 but less that a billion, so it *can* be calculated in minutes if done efficiently

Comment: Thank you! I first did it by hand (after reading our answer) and then optimized my code, now both ways work!

Answer (score 0):

The Question essentially asks you to find the LCM of the first 20 numbers...

```
lcm = 1
for i = 2 to 20
   lcm = (i * lcm) / gcd(lcm,i)
```

Answer (score 0):

A far simpler solution would be to use your algorithm but increment by 2520 rather than 1, here is my C++ solution.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int check = 2520;
    int i = 11;
    while (i != 20)
    {
        i ++;
        if (check % i != 0)
        {
            check +=2520;
            i = 1;
        }
    }
    cout << check << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see above, I also start at the number 2520, and set i to equal 11. We can make these optimizations, as we have been given the necessary information in the question.